# How to use g++ in a docker container

Tags: docker

I want to build and run the C++ program in a docker container. I found this https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-gxx/dockerfile

my dockerfile:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-gcc
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN apk add --no-cache g++ &&\ g++ main.cpp -o myapp
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

I'm running `$ docker build` and get the following error:

```
/bin/sh:  g++: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache g++ &&\ g++ main.cpp -o myapp' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I actually don't know why but you need to put split you `RUN` and have separately `RUN g++ main.cpp -o myapp`.

Comment: `g++` is not available when it's on the same line, but you can do `RUN apk add --no-cache g++ && /usr/bin/g++ main.cpp -o myapp` and it will work.

Comment: You've quoted the space in front the command, so it's trying to run ` g++` ("space" "g" "plus" "plus").  Remove the extra backslash.  (Also notice the double space in the error message.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FROM frolvlad/alpine-gxx` instead.